# How many Krakens do you earn in black market brawlers?

Tags: league-of-legends

For the new game mode [Black Market Brawlers](http://na.lolesports.com/articles/get-ready-black-market-brawlers) it says "You earn Krakens passively, as well as through kills, assists, taking objectives, and counter jungling".

How many Krakens do you earn for :

- A Kill:
- A Assist:
- Killing a Tower:
- Killing a Inhibitor:
- Killing Dragon:
- Killing Baron:
- Killing A Single Monster in Enemies Jungle:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two Krakens for a kill, one for everything else you listed.  A few notes:

1. The whole team is awarded a Kraken on Dragon and Baron kills (even teammates that are not alive when the monster dies).
2. You also passively generate 1 Kraken every 60 seconds.
3. Enemy jungle camps only give Krakens for the big monster.

More data about BMB available in the [Wiki Article](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Market_Brawlers).

Comment: Your whole team gets 1 for Baron and Dragon according to the wiki, which seems pretty good.

Comment: Yep, I suppose that's not immediately intuitive, so I've edited.

Comment: Only large monsters in the enemy jungle are worth a kraken.